# JSON, how to add two words in json format? Se below, hard to put an title on this one

Tags: json

I have an iOS app (in Swift 3.0) that is question based. Simply you get questions from different categories like Science, Chemistry etc. In a JSON file i define those questions. In code section "answers": the user get the correct answer.

My question is if I can add another string/word in there. Is that possible and how do I do that? Can I do like this:   `"answers": ["Astronomi, Ekologi"],` ?  So the user can answer either both and get the correct answer?

Thank you for helping me, I´m a beginner app developer, so still learning everyday :)

```
  {
  "question": "Vad kallas läran om rymden?",
  "answers": ["Astronomi"],
  "correctIndex": 0,
  "feedback": "Astronomi är läran om rymden.",
  "category": "Fysik",
  "subcategory": "Astronomi",
  "isTest": true
  },
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 var obj = {
   "question": "Vad kallas läran om rymden?",
   "answers": ["Astronomi"],
   "correctIndex": 0,
   "feedback": "Astronomi är läran om rymden.",
   "category": "Fysik",
   "subcategory": "Astronomi",
   "isTest": true
 }
```

and in your swift

This iterates through the list of answers and returns `true` if is in there.

```
for answer in obj.answers { 
   if answer == user_answer {
      return true; 
   }
}
```

***Extra Credit***

I know javascript has a shorthand for this you would have to look up if swift does?

```
return (user_answer in obj.answers);
```

This is shorthand for the above and is found in some high level languages. (not swift as pointed out by Quentin)

```
if ( "foo" in ["baz","bar","foo"] ) { 
    // foo found ... 
}
```

This also applied to objects like this:

```
if ( "question" in obj ) { 
   // obj["question"] exists...
}
```

Comment: `in` works on property names, not values, so that JS example wouldn't work.

Comment: Yes but that only compares with one answer, doesn´t it?  I want to have two answers the user can input only, both om them the correct answer. Like it is know its working already, do you understand what I mean?